# How to re-arrange string so that same characters are not next to each other?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting

How to re-arrange string so that same characters are not next to each other and if there are many alternative sorting options we'll choose the one which is alphabetically sorted?

i.e.

```
AAABBBB -> BABABAB
AAABBB -> ABABAB
BCDDEEEF -> BCEDEDEF
BACHH -> ABHCH
```

Pseudo code or something would be useful.

Comment: "choose the one which is alphabetically sorted"? What does that mean?

Comment: @cicto AAABBB -> ABABAB not like BABABA

Comment: Retracted close vote. the linked question does not have the 'choose the alphabetically first' criteria.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution:

```
Find all permutations of the string
Find all that don't have repeating characters
Find the first alphabetically
```

Comment: +1 for great simple solution. Could be a tad slow though.

Comment: This solution will be prohibitively expensive on any reasonable-sized string. It's great to have a naive solution available, but I doubt this is as efficient as it can be.